# How to implement following-sibling axis of xpath alternative in Beautifulsoup Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to collect the text using Bs4, selenium and Python I want to get the text `"Lisa Staprans"` using:

```
name = str(profilePageSource.find(class_="hzi-font hzi-Man-Outline").div.get_text().encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]
```

Here is the code:

```
<div class="profile-about-right">
 <div class="text-bold">
  SF Peninsula Interior Design Firm
  <br/>
  Best of Houzz 2015
 </div>
 <br/>
 <div class="page-tags" style="display:none">
  page_type: pro_plus_profile
 </div>
 <div class="pro-info-horizontal-list text-m text-dt-s">
  <div class="info-list-label">
   <i class="hzi-font hzi-Ruler">
   </i>
   <div class="info-list-text">
    <span class="hide" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcr
umb">
     <a href="http://www.houzz.com/professionals/c/Menlo-Park--CA" itemprop="url
">
      <span itemprop="title">
       Professionals
      </span>
     </a>
    </span>
    <span itemprop="child" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Bre
adcrumb">
     <a href="http://www.houzz.com/professionals/interior-designer/c/Menlo-Park-
-CA" itemprop="url">
      <span itemprop="title">
       Interior Designers &amp; Decorators
      </span>
     </a>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info-list-label">
   <i class="hzi-font hzi-Man-Outline">
   </i>
   <div class="info-list-text">
    <b>
     Contact
    </b>
    : Lisa Staprans
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know how it would be.

Comment: hzi-font hzi-Man-Outline has no child so you are going in the wrong way

Comment: Yes please let me know how i can select the second class="info-list-text"

Comment: I am actually using webdriver way of using selenium but short would be I think to use : `find(class_="info-list-text").get_text()` (or maybe `innerHtml`) and then you split with the ` : `

Comment: `print(profilePageSource.find_all('div', {'class': "info-list-text"})[1].text)`? Also, do you want to do this use selenium or bs4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you are using Beautifulsoup since you are using `class_` attribute dictionary-
If there is one `div` with class name `hzi-font hzi-Man-Outline` then try-

```
str(profilePageSource.find(class_="hzi-font hzi-Man-Outline").findNext('div').get_text().split(":")[-1]).strip()
```

Extracts  `'Lisa Staprans'`

Here `findNext` navigates to next div and extracts text.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now but I would do :

```
profilePageSource.find_element_by_class_name("info-list-text").get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Then you will have to split the result considering the `:` (if it's always the case).

For more informations : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with this part:

```
find(class_="hzi-font hzi-Man-Outline")
```

An easy way to get the right information can be: right click on the element you need in the page source by inspecting it with Google Chrome, copy the xpath of the element, and then use:

```
profilePageSource.find_element_by_xpath(<xpath copied from Chorme>).text
```

Hope it helps.